# Can't click on a button using Selenium (web scrape)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to click on this button so that I can proceed to the next page but doesn't seem to be working for me. I am trying to click on the 'Search for an inspection report' button.

This is the xpath for this source. //*[@id="btnOK"] . And so I was trying to use driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btnOK"]').click() and it gives me an error saying unable to locate element.

Here is the link to the site.
https://www.halton.ca/For-Residents/Food-Safety/Dinewise/Search-Directory-of-Food-Premises-Dinewise

Any help would be great.

Comment: Pls check whether my code works for u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the button is present within a different `iframe`. In order to click that button, u have to switch focus to that `iframe`. This is how u do it:

```
iframe = driver.find_element_by_id("iframe-form")

driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btnOK"]')

btn.click()
```

Plus, another thing to note is that the `xpath` u have provided is wrong. U have missed a `*` in the `xpath`. The right `xpath` is `'//*[@id="btnOK"]'`.

Complete code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://www.halton.ca/For-Residents/Food-Safety/Dinewise/Search-Directory-of-Food-Premises-Dinewise')

iframe = driver.find_element_by_id("iframe-form")

driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btnOK"]')

btn.click()
```

Hope that this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution using webdriver wait:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
wd = webdriver.Chrome('<PATH_TO_CHROMEDRIVER>', options=chrome_options)

# load page via selenium
wd.get("https://www.halton.ca/For-Residents/Food-Safety/Dinewise/Search-Directory-of-Food-Premises-Dinewise")
# wait for iframe, switch to it
frame = WebDriverWait(wd, 30).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"iframe-form")))
# wait for button, scroll to it, click it
btn = WebDriverWait(wd, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'btnOK')))
wd.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", btn)
wd.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", btn)
```